# In Solaris, link dynamic library error when using /usr/sfw/bin/gcc

Tags: c, gcc, hyperlink, solaris

all:
    I am working on Solaris 10, and meet the following issue:

```
There is ODBC dynamic library in /usr/local/lib:

lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root          16 Jun 26  2012 libodbc.so -> libodbc.so.2.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root          16 Jun 26  2012 libodbc.so.2 -> libodbc.so.2.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root     root     1874776 Jun 26  2012 libodbc.so.2.0.0
```

The makefile likes this:

```
gcc  -o a a.c -lodbc
```

When I use  /usr/local/bin/gcc to complie the program, the compile is OK.
  But when I use /usr/sfw/bin/gcc to complie the program, get the following error:

ld: fatal: library -lodbc: not found

But crle command output:

```
 Configuration file [version 4]: /var/ld/ld.config  
 Platform:     32-bit MSB SPARC
 Default Library Path (ELF):   /lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib:/opt/DSI/32:/usr/local/asg_mysql/lib
 Trusted Directories (ELF):    /lib/secure:/usr/lib/secure  (system default)

 Command line:
 crle -c /var/ld/ld.config -l /lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib:/opt/DSI/32:/usr/local/asg_mysql/lib
```

It seems OK.

So is there any difference when using gcc? Thanks very much in advance!
Best Regards
Nan Xiao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `/usr/local/lib` is not in the default search path for the linker. Use the `-L` option to add it:

```
$ /usr/sfw/bin/gcc your_file.c -o your_program -L/usr/local/lib -lodbc
```

Comment: But crle output: crle -c /var/ld/ld.config -l /lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib:/opt/DSI/32:/usr/local/asg_mysql/lib. The /usr/local/lib is in path.

Comment: @NanXiao Yes, but it still seems GCC does _not_ use that path, or it should have worked shouldn't it?

Comment: Thanks! Per your point, /usr/sfw/bin/gcc doesn't act totally like GNU gcc. Is it right?

Comment: @NanXiao It's the Solaris distribution of GCC, so it's a "true" GCC. It's just not built with the same flags as the one you have in `/usr/local`.